# Make columns always equal height? (Foundation 5)

Tags: zurb-foundation

How to create a layout as shown in the image? The first column left and the second column right should always be the same height, **depending of the first column height**, using Foundation 5.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foundation equalizer will make them even, but based on the longer one.
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html

you can use jQuery to do it yourself like this (this can work with many columns, and with any column as the one determining the size:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  sizeRow();

  function sizeRow() {
    var $col = $('.sizeRow .size-by-me');
    var height = $col.height();
    $col.siblings('.size-me').height(height);
  }
});
```

```css
.small-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.col1 {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #F00;
}
.col2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row sizeRow">
  <div class="small-6 columns size-by-me col1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="small-6 columns col2 size-me">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting such usefull information. I tried the equalizer but indeed as you said it will adjust the height to the longer one. Is there a way to fit the height to the smallest?